# Как поднять подчеркивание блока CSS, чтобы сам контейнер остался неизменным

Tags: html

```css
.cat_fasads {
  background-color: #202020;  
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.cat_img {
  margin: 35px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 223px;
}

.cat_name {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.cat_name:after {
  display: block; /*превращаем его в блочный элемент*/
  content: ""; /*контента в данном блоке не будет поэтому в кавычках ничего не ставим*/
  height: 4px; /*задаём высоту линии*/
  width: 0%; /*задаём начальную ширину элемента (линии)*/
  background-color: #D6BA8C; /*цвет фона элемента*/
}

.cat_name:hover:after,
.cat_name:focus:after {
width: 400px;
}
.cat_name:hover{
color:#D6BA8C;

} 

.cat_name:hover {
  color:#D6BA8C;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
    <div class="categories">
      <div class="desct_left">
        <a class="cat_name" href="#">
          <div class="cat_fasads">
            <img class="cat_img" src="../bootstrap/img/bravo-300x223.png" alt="Фрезеровка Браво">
            Фасад "Браво"
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="desct_center">
        <a class="cat_name" href="#">
          <div class="cat_fasads">
            <img class="cat_img" src="../bootstrap/img/standart-300x223.png" alt="Серия Стандарт">
            Серия "Стандарт"
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="desct_right">      
        <a class="cat_name" href="#">
          <div class="cat_fasads">
            <img class="cat_img" src="../bootstrap/img/optima-300x223.png" alt="Серия Оптима">
            Фасад "Оптима"
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Получается между блоками появляется промежуток для подчеркивания, как его убрать? чтобы подчеркивание было внутри блока?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавим для `.cat_name` `position: relative;`, а для `.cat_name:after` `position: absolute;` и `bottom: 0;`.

```css
.cat_fasads {
  background-color: #202020;  
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 35px;
}

.cat_img {
  margin: 35px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 223px;
}

.cat_name {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.cat_name:after {
  position: absolute;
  display: block; /*превращаем его в блочный элемент*/
  content: ""; /*контента в данном блоке не будет поэтому в кавычках ничего не ставим*/
  height: 4px; /*задаём высоту линии*/
  width: 0%; /*задаём начальную ширину элемента (линии)*/
  background-color: #D6BA8C; /*цвет фона элемента*/
  bottom: 0;
}

.cat_name:hover:after,
.cat_name:focus:after {
width: 400px;
}
.cat_name:hover{
color:#D6BA8C;

} 

.cat_name:hover {
  color:#D6BA8C;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="categories">
      <div class="desct_left">
        <a class="cat_name" href="#">
          <div class="cat_fasads">
            <img class="cat_img" src="../bootstrap/img/bravo-300x223.png" alt="Фрезеровка Браво">
            Фасад "Браво"
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="desct_center">
        <a class="cat_name" href="#">
          <div class="cat_fasads">
            <img class="cat_img" src="../bootstrap/img/standart-300x223.png" alt="Серия Стандарт">
            Серия "Стандарт"
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="desct_right">      
        <a class="cat_name" href="#">
          <div class="cat_fasads">
            <img class="cat_img" src="../bootstrap/img/optima-300x223.png" alt="Серия Оптима">
            Фасад "Оптима"
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```